# Determinant of a matrix equal to zero

Tags: matrices, determinant

If it is given that $B^2=0$. Then can I directly take the determinant on both sides and prove that determinant of $B = 0$?

---

$Given: B^2 = 0$

---

*Taking determinant both sides*

$|B^2|=|B|^2$

$|B|^2=|0|$

$|B|=0$

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should add an extra step: $\left|B^2\right|=|B|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Since $\det(B^n) = \det(B)^n$ (the determinant is multiplicative), we have that

$$\det(B^2) = 0 \implies \det(B)^2 = 0 \implies |\det(B)|= 0 \implies \det(B) = 0$$